# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: json, android-studio, retrofit2

Как можно обойти ошибку `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING`?
Для получения данных и обработки использую Retrofit2.
Дело в том что JSON должен иметь вид

```
[
    {
       "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "profession": "Администратор",
            "finance": {
                "name": "100"
            },
            "company_name": "",
            "pros": "",
            "cons": ""
        }
     }
]
```

но иногда может иметь вид

```
 [
    {
       "user": {
               "id": 1,
                    "profession": "Администратор",
                    "finance": "",
                    "company_name": "",
                    "pros": "",
                    "cons": ""
                }
     }
]
```

Во втором случае и вызывается ошибка, помогите как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Проблема в finance, потому что ожидается, что там придет объект, а приходит строка пустая. Если нет доступа к отправляющей стороне, чтобы вообще не слать значение, если оно пустое, то я думаю нужно просто написать свой десериализатор, чтобы обрабатывать эту ситуацию вручную

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста примером, если не сложно